# What are the differences between Zigbee and Zigbee PRO?

Tags: protocols, zigbee

What are the differences (if any) between Zigbee and Zigbee PRO ?
I cannot find anything specific on Wikipedia, and on the [official Zigbee site](https://docs.zigbee.org/zigbee-docs/dcn/07-5299.pdf) it all sums up to some *optimizations* here and there.
Are there any differences in practical use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any differences in practical use, and I don't believe the non-PRO standard really went far after the two were defined in 2007.

This [EE Times article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276377) describes the differences between the two.

According to the ZigBee Alliance, [ZigBee](http://www.zigbee.org/Products/CompliantPlatforms/ZigBeeFeatureSet.aspx) networks will scale to hundreds of devices, and [ZigBee PRO](http://www.zigbee.org/Products/CompliantPlatforms/ZigBeePROFeatureSet.aspx) networks scale to thousands.

I personally consider the non-PRO ZigBee to be a legacy protocol, and would use ZigBee PRO for any serious projects.

[As an aside, Digi International's popular XBee radio modules use the "PRO" designation for higher-powered modules with a longer range, which is completely unrelated to ZigBee/ZigBee PRO, but could lead to confusion.]